# Build all the artifacts then test them

Tags: maven

I'm building a multi-module project. One of those modules contains tools for tests that I'll reuse during the tests of my project.

Concretely, here's my expected structure:

```
project-parent
+ project-a
  / depends on project-testing (scope:test)
+ project-b
  / depends on project-a (scope:compile)
  / depends on project-testing (scope:test)
+ project-testing (contains nice tools)
  / depends on project-a (scope:compile)
  / depends on project-b (scope:compile)
```

How to solve this need in Maven? I believe I would like to actually build all the artifacts, then only when done test them.

I've seen that Guava, for instance, has the following structure:

```
guava-parent
+ guava
+ guava-testing
  / depends on guava (scope:compile)
+ guava-tests
  / depends on guava (scope:compile)
  / depends on guava-testing (scope:test)
```

But this structure annoys me because I've several modules and I want to keep the testing classes as close as possible to the tested classes, meaning in the same module.

Comment: What is the actual problem? It seems everything is working as you expect.

Comment: @Tunaki it's not. I'm trying to have my code and test of project A in `project-a/src/main/java` and `project-a/src/test/java` respectively. `project-a/src/test/java` depends on `project-testing` which in turn depends on `project-a/src/main/java`. There is a kind of circular dependency but in different phases. However Maven doesn't allow that.

Comment: Why would `project-testing` depend on `project-a`?

Comment: @Tunaki Because it does and it makes sense it does.

Comment: Why? A utility project designed to help testing the main big project shouldn't depend on that main project.

Comment: @Tunaki Well [tell that to Guava](https://github.com/google/guava). I'm trying to solve the same problem they have, but with a different approach, by keeping the `src/main` and `src/test` in the same module.